Optimizing Cassandra Table Design for Queries Involving Two Partition Keys
I’m designing a Cassandra table and need advice on the best schema design to handle my query patterns efficiently. The primary queries are as follows:

90% of the queries involve both account_id and actor_id.
10% of the queries involve only account_id.

Given these requirements, I initially thought of using both account_id and actor_id as partition keys. Here are my specific questions and concerns:
Current Considerations and Schema
Option 1: Composite Partition Key
CREATE TABLE search_table (
    account_id UUID,
    actor_id UUID,
    other_columns ...,
    PRIMARY KEY ((account_id, actor_id))
);

•   Pros: Efficient for queries with both account_id and actor_id.
•   Cons: Inefficient for queries with only account_id since it requires scanning multiple partitions.
Option 2: Single Partition Key with Clustering Column
CREATE TABLE search_table (
    account_id UUID,
    actor_id UUID,
    other_columns ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id, actor_id)
);


Pros: Efficient for both types of queries without requiring ALLOW
FILTERING
Cons: Risk of very large partitions due to billions of records.

Considering Bucketing
To manage partition sizes effectively, I considered using bucketing:j
CREATE TABLE search_table (
    bucket_id INT,
    account_id UUID,
    actor_id UUID,
    other_columns ...,
    PRIMARY KEY ((bucket_id, account_id), actor_id)
);

•   Pros: Balanced partition sizes, efficient for both query types.
•   Cons: Requires calculating bucket_id in application logic and might add complexity.
Using IN Clause for Efficient Queries
If both account_id and actor_id are partition keys:
SELECT * FROM search_table 
WHERE account_id = ? AND actor_id IN (?, ?, ...);

•   Pros: Simplifies querying multiple actor_id values within the same account_id.
•   Cons: Performance overhead if the list of actor_id values is large.
Questions

What is the best table design to handle my query patterns efficiently?
Is using both account_id and actor_id as partition keys recommended, or should I rely on a different approach like bucketing?
How do IN queries perform in Cassandra when used with partition keys, and are there practical limits on their usage?

Any insights, recommendations, or alternative strategies to manage partition sizes while maintaining efficient queries would be greatly appreciated!

I would recommend not focusing on the storage but on how the application will query the data.
If the application query is like "get [details] of account X AND actor Y" then the data needs to be partitioned by both the account AND actor so the schema would look like:
CREATE TABLE table_by_account_and_actor (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY((account, actor))
)

and the app query would require both columns for the partition key:
SELECT ...
    FROM table_by_account_and_actor
    WHERE account = ?
    AND actor = ?

If the application query is like "get [details of] actors for account X" where each account has one or more rows of actors then the table will be partitioned by the account with a cluster (rows) of actors:
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(account, actor)
)

and the app query would only require the account to retrieve a list of actors:
SELECT ...
    FROM accounts
    WHERE account = ?

You didn't explain your use case with enough details so I don't have enough information to know how an account can have billions of actors but in any case, I wouldn't use buckets in this scenario because it wouldn't be possible to know what bucket value is required to query the data.
I would also discourage using the IN() operator. It can be acceptable to use for querying 2 or maybe 3 partitions but anything more than that can result in unpredictable performance impacts on your cluster because it puts a lot of pressure on the coordinator to coordinate separate requests for each IN() item. Cheers!
